# Obtaining a substring value for a delimited String of unknown length

Tags: java, substring

Given the String data, delimited by `:` and comma separated

```
String times =  6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third
```

I need to get the third value from the last comma separated list, in this above case `15000`

Or `20000` in the below case

```
String times =  6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third,24:20000:fourth
```

Or `30000` in the below case

```
String times =  
         6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third,24:20000:fourth,30:30000:fourth
```

Something like:

```
public String getLastTimeFromCommaSeparatedList() {
    return times.substring(mileages.lastIndexOf(':') + 2);
}
```

I'm unclear how I can get the value I need, given the comma separated list is of an unknown length.

Comment: Look into `String.split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use substring with lastIndexOf and split like this:

```
times.substring(time.lastIndexOf(",")).split(":")[1]
```

**Demo**

```
String[] times = {"6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third",
        "6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third,24:20000:fourth",
        "6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third,24:20000:fourth,30:30000:fourth"
};
for (String time : times) {
    System.out.println(
            time.substring(time.lastIndexOf(",")).split(":")[1]
    );
}
```

**Outputs**

```
15000
20000
30000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

```java
String times = "6:10000:first,12:12000:second,18:15000:third,24:20000:fourth,30:30000:fourth";
java.util.regex.Pattern pttrn = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\d+):[a-z]+$");
java.util.regex.Matcher mtchr = pttrn.matcher(times);
if (mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println(mtchr.group(1));
}
else {
    System.out.println("Nothing found.");
}
```

Explanation of the pattern

- `(\\d+)` a string of one or more digits.
- `:` the colon character
- `[a-z]+` one or more lowercase letters
- `$` the end of the input string

So the pattern looks for digits followed by a colon followed by lowercase letters at the end of the input string. It also groups the digits.

It works for every sample string in your question.